# Why return false in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-adapter

I'm writing an Android app that uses an AdapterView. There are multiple calls to `IsInFilterMode()` in the AdapterView class which simply is a one line function that returns false. I can't override the function so I can't for the life of me figure out why this function exists if it just returns false. The description says that it returns true if it's in filter mode. Here is the definition of `IsInFilterMode()`:

```
 /**
 * Indicates whether this view is in filter mode. Filter mode can for instance
 * be enabled by a user when typing on the keyboard.
 *
 * @return True if the view is in filter mode, false otherwise.
 */
boolean isInFilterMode() {
    return false;
}
```

I am relatively new to Java so perhaps I'm missing something that is typical to Java source code here? Is there other code that is be obfuscated from me?

Comment: Why can't you override the method?  Is the class marked as final?  Looks like a default value that you're expected to override when you extend this class.

Comment: The default return value is `false`, but custom implementations (childs of `AdapterView`) are free to override `isInFilterMode()` to suit their capabilities. The default `AdapterView` just does not support filter mode.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was being being a noob. Android Studio marked my override as not overriding anything from the super class. I was trying to override it from the ArrayAdapter instead of from the AdapterView. My mistake! No wonder why I couldn't find anything on Google. Early Monday mornings my brain does not work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the lack of a visibility modifier is often referred to as *package-private*. It is in between `protected` and `private` on the visibility scale- only other classes within the same package can override package-private methods. See [Controlling Access to members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more information.

The Android framework uses this often- it allows the framework to override those methods without allowing the end users (Android developers) to do the same and potentially interfere with how the framework operates.

In this case, the default for `AdapterView`s is to not support filter mode at all.

Some `AdapterView` subclasses do support it. For example, [`AbsListView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java) and it's descendants do. In the case of `AbsListView`, this method returns the value of an internal property that tracks whether or not the list is actually in filter mode.